# Использование заголовков в PHP

Tags: php

У меня следующая ситуация. В начало скрипта PHP я вставила заголовок:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
?>
```

Однако, несмотря на эту "обавку", все равно получила ошибку:

> "An error occured while accessing the tiles. Cross-domain access
>   restrictions are applied on map tiles for WebGL. Either use CORS on
>   remote domain (http://enable-cors.org/) or place your application on
>   the same domain as tiles (hosting app and tiles on the same domain or
>   running a tile proxy)."

В качестве `remote domain` как раз я хочу использовать свой сервер, но почему мой заголовок тем не менее не проходит?! Заранее благодарю за какую-либо подсказку.

Comment: Не используются ли еще какие-то данные с сервера помимо этого PHP-скрипта? В консоли браузера в Network вы видите заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin для запроса к этому PHP-скрипту или заголовок просто не отправляется?

Comment: Тогда подробнее - я на своем сервере в скрипте PHP использую WebGLEarth, а там используются данные с их сервера и все прекрасно работает, пока дело не доходит до данных с моего же сервера

Answer (score 1):

Более полные заголовки для включения CORS

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
```